# UILabel Not Showing Up On View

Tags: swift, xcode

[image]

I just started learning how to code without using storyboards programatically, so please treat me as a beginner... Even though my image shows up on the screen, the label doesn't... I am a little confused as to why this is going on and I appreciate your help. Again, I'm a beginner, do don't mind if its a silly mistake!!!

```
import UIKit

class LocationRequestController : UIViewController
{
    let imageView: UIImageView =
    {
        let iconImageView = UIImageView()
        iconImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        iconImageView.image = UIImage(named: "blue-pin")
        return iconImageView
    }()

    let allowLocationLabel : UILabel =
    {
        let label = UILabel()
        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Allow Location\n", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 24)])
        attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "Please enable location services For The Map To Work!", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)]))

        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.attributedText = attributedText

        return label
    }()
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureViewAppearance()
    }

    func configureViewAppearance()
    {
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 140, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
        imageView.centerX(inView: view)

        view.addSubview(allowLocationLabel)
        allowLocationLabel.anchor(top: imageView.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 32, paddingLeft: 32, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 32, width: 0, height: 0)
        allowLocationLabel.centerX(inView: view)
    }
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: did you check the console for broken constraints? also when using autolayout you need to mark the element as `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false to follow the autolayout changes

Comment: Hey Joshua, thank you for trying to help me with this question, as you can see, I have found the error. I would delete this question as it is a bad one, but stack overflow wouldn't let me do that... So please don't downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the problem:

The text color was automatically set to .white, so that's the reason why it didn't seem to show up! Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add one line `label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`

```
let allowLocationLabel : UILabel =
    {
        let label = UILabel()
        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Allow Location\n", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 24)])
        attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "Please enable location services For The Map To Work!", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)]))

        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.attributedText = attributedText
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
```

Comment: Jawad, it is still not working.... The label is not being displayed under the image

Comment: what are. you using for setting constraint ?

Comment: I found the answer, I am using an extension of UIView and then adding constrains by calling the functions inside that function

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, I appreciate it!